# OTTO + Dagger - Can't get event message on Application class

Tags: android, dagger-2, otto

I'm learning to use **otto** as an event system. I can register my activity and receive the message from `bus.post()`. However, if I register my `Application class`, the subscribed method doesn't get called. What I'm I doing wrong?

This is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Inject
BusWorker busWorker;
@Inject
LogWorker logWorker;

ActivityMainBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    inject();

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    busWorker.register(this);
    binding.setHandlers(this);
}

@Subscribe
public void recievedMessage(Message message) {
    logWorker.log("recievedMessage: " + message.getMessage());
}

public void onClickButton(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            busWorker.post("Test message");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    busWorker.unRegister(this);
}

void inject() {
    ((App) getApplication()).getGeneralComponent().inject(this);
    ((App) getApplication()).getSchoolComponent().inject(this);
}
}
```

App class

```
public class App extends Application {

private NetComponent netComponent;
private GeneralComponent generalComponent;

@Inject
public App() {}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    netComponent = DaggerNetComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .netModule(new NetModule())
            .build();

    generalComponent = DaggerGeneralComponent.builder()
            .netComponent(netComponent)
            .generalModule(new GeneralModule())
            .build();

    netComponent.BusWorker().register(this);
}

@Subscribe
public void recievedMessage(Message message) {
    netComponent.logWorker().log("recievedMessage: " + message.getMessage());
}

public GeneralComponent getGeneralComponent() {
    return generalComponent;
}

public NetComponent getNetComponent() {
    return netComponent;
}
}
```

My NetModule (partially)

```
@Module
public class NetModule {

    public NetModule() {

    }

    @Provides
    @NetScope
    BusWorker provideBusWorker(){

        return new BusWorker();
    }
}
```

NetScope

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NetScope {

}
```

My NetComponent

```
@NetScope
@Component(modules={AppModule.class, NetModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {

    NetWorker netWorker();
    DbWorker dbWorker();
    LogWorker logWorker();
    SharedPreferencesWorker sharedPreferences();
    BusWorker BusWorker();
}
```

Comment: Is your bus `@Singleton` annotated or otherwise scoped? My guess is, you're subscribing to two different bus objects in activity / application

Comment: I just edited the original post by adding my netModule, Scope and component. I'm I missing something to make sure I'm registering to the same bus?

Comment: Looks okay, you could still just quickly check it by logging the objects and comparing them

Comment: I used busWorker.getBus().equals(FragmentTest.busWorker.getBus()) and got false. Is that the right way to compare both objects?

Comment: You don't show how you create your `SchoolComponent` or what it is, but it sems you have 2 different objects, so are you maybe creating another `NetComponent` to be used by `SchoolComponent`?

Comment: You're right. I was registering on 2 different bus objects. I sorted out and will post the code in a moment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the components, modules and the way they're being initialized in the Application class. This is the working code where the right message is received in the Application, Activity and fragment:

SchoolComponent

```
@SchoolScope
@Component(modules={SchoolModule.class})
public interface SchoolComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);

    void inject(FragmentTest fragment);

    void inject(App app);

    School provideSchool();
}
```

NetComponent

```
@NetScope
@Component(modules={NetModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);

    void inject(FragmentTest fragment);

    void inject(App app);

    NetWorker provideNetWorker();
    DbWorker provideDbWorker();
    LogWorker provideLogWorker();
    SharedPreferencesWorker provideSharedPreferences();
}
```

NetModule

```
@Module
public class NetModule {

    @Provides
    @NetScope
    SharedPreferencesWorker provideSharedPreferences(){

        return new SharedPreferencesWorker();
    }

    @Provides
    @NetScope
    NetWorker provideNetWorker(){

        return new NetWorker();
    }

    @Provides
    @NetScope
    DbWorker provideDbWorker(){

        return new DbWorker();
    }

    @Provides
    @NetScope
    LogWorker provideLogWorker(){

        return new LogWorker();
    }

    @Provides
    @NetScope
    BusWorker provideBusWorker(){

        return new BusWorker();
    }
}
```

Application class

```
public class App extends Application {

    private NetComponent netComponent;

    private SchoolComponent schoolComponent;

    @Inject
    BusWorker busWorker;

    @Inject
    public App() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        schoolComponent = DaggerSchoolComponent.create();
        schoolComponent.inject(this);

        netComponent = DaggerNetComponent.create();
        netComponent.inject(this);

        busWorker.register(this);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void recievedMessage(Message message) {

        Log.d("Dagger", "recievedMessage App: " + message.getMessage());
    }

    public SchoolComponent getSchoolComponent() {

        return schoolComponent;
    }

    public NetComponent getNetComponent() {

        return netComponent;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    BusWorker busWorker;
    @Inject
    LogWorker logWorker;
    @Inject
    School school;

    @Bind(R.id.name)
    TextView name;

    ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        inject();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        busWorker.register(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        busWorker.unRegister(this);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void recievedMessage(Message message) {

        logWorker.log("recievedMessage Activity: " + message.getMessage());
    }

    public void onClickButton(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.button:

                busWorker.post(new Message("blablabla"));

                break;

            default:

                break;
        }
    }

    void inject() {

        ((App) getApplication()).getNetComponent().inject(this);
        ((App) getApplication()).getSchoolComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```